# P2238 Positive Current Circuit Low on Toyota Camry 2004

Tags: toyota, sensor, o2-sensor

I'm getting P2238 Positive Current Circuit Low from my car, for O2 Sensor in Bank 1 Sensor 1 for my Toyota Camry 2004 (4 cylinder).  What is it and how can I fix this problem?  From what I've read on it, the answers are all over the board, so I am not sure what to think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to check your O2 sensor, is to record all the codes (On paper, or whatever) and swap the sensors. If the code goes to bank 2, than you know you need a sensor. These are sometimes hard to find, due to the many things that can trigger an O2 fault. This is just a quick way to check the sensors, just be sure to reset the codes after recording them.

Comment: Yeah, one could do that to isolate a faulty sensor.
But, there IS a simple diagnostic procedure, as done by Chris Fix
in YouTube video. Check the resistance between the black wires
after unplugging the sensor connector. An open circuit (infinite ohms)
means that sensor is bad, needs replacement. Don't use Bosch sensors on
Camry, use OEM Denso, that's consensus.

Answer (score 2):

A 2004 Camry SE uses three sensors:  an Upstream Oxygen Sensor, an Upstream  Air Fuel Ratio Sensor and a Downstream Oxygen Sensor.

Your "Bank 1 Sensor 1" error indicates a problem with Air Fuel Ratio Sensor, not Oxygen Sensor

These two sensors are NOT swappable and cannot be used for troubleshooting.